# Java printDialog takes long time to show when called for the first time

Tags: java, printdialog

I am using the default code to print from Java (below).
The problem is that the dialog takes more than 10 seconds to show, when called for the first time.
if called again, it just popup very quickly...
Is there a way to solve that ?? or maybe call it silently when the application starts ?? call a special method that might be taking long???  any help is appreciated !
Code:

```
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
job.setPrintable(this);
if (job.printDialog() == true) {
    try {
        job.print();
    } catch (PrinterException ex) { }
}
```

Comment: It's likely trying to resovle the list of available printer. Do y have any network attached printers?

Comment: @MadProgrammer,  I have a wireless printer configured, but offline. I don't really use it always. Everytime I need to use it, I must connect to its own wireless network, which throws me offline. I am trying to print to cups-pdf

Comment: You were definitely right  @MadProgrammer, When I disabled the printer, the dialog popsup in a second.. Do you think I should call some function to resolve the list when the program starts ?

Comment: Don't think there are any you could call, this is resolved by calls through the OS.  You could take a look at the [Print Services](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/services.html) API which might provide you with the ability to more selective, but at the end of the day, this is a OS issue...